# A quick question on Signed measures and the Legesgue Decomposition Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a (positive) $\sigma$-finite measure space. Then the Lebgesgue Decomposition Theorem states  if $\nu$ is a sigma finite measure (positive, signed or complex), then there exits two measures $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$, such that $\nu=\nu_0+\nu_1$, $\nu_0$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and $\mu$ and $\nu_1$ and mutually singular.

My question is that can this result be extended where $\mu$ is an arbitrary signed or complex measure?  I can't seem to find a proof of this and when I try the obvious thing by using the Jordan decomposition on $\mu$, things get muddled (or maybe I am not seeing it clearly) Similarly can this relaxation on $\mu$ carry over for the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, if $\nu<<\mu$ .

Thanks in advance any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the concepts "$\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$" and "$\nu$ is mutually singular w.r.t. $\mu$" if $\mu$ is a signed or complex measure? For example, for the first case, the definition "if $\mu(E) = 0$, then $\nu(E) = 0$" does not seem to be correct, consider e.g. $d\mu = \chi_{[0,1]} dx - \chi_{[-1,0)} \, dx$ and $d\nu = \chi_{[0,1]}$. You should probably require "if $|\mu|(E) = 0$, then $\nu(E) =0$". In this case, the approach through the Jordan decomposition should be relatively easy.

Comment: Can you elaborate or refer tome to a text?

Comment: I will try to find one for you.